# Disable panning/scrolling in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, touch

I have a drawing app that doesn't work in IE because the page scrolls.

I am using the `pointerdown`, `pointermove`, etc events.

I tried `preventDefault` which works for WebKit, but it has no effect for IE.

I also tried `overflow:hidden`, `touch-action:none`, but they also seem to have no effect.

What can I do?

The problem is on a MS Surface.

I am using Microsoft Surface Input Simulator with IE11 on Windows 7 and have recreated the problem, but can't seem to fix it.

Update: The `touch-action:none` option works for the Desktop version of IE on the MS Surface, but not for the App version. But it would be much better for the support people if it could work on both.

Answer (score 0):

you may just have to wrap content in a div with position: relative and overflow: hidden though I would need to see some code to be certain.

Comment: On the Touch Simulator, adding overflow:hidden to the html,body was ineffective.

Comment: The element in question was a position:fixed and covered the whole page (like a modal dialog). The problem was that dragging your finger would scroll the page behind the dialog, even if the page was overflow:hidden.